# $.ajax: How to override default http headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, http-headers

I'm using `jQuery.ajax` to make HTTP connections. In my project I'd like to set custom http headers, but I'd like to send only the ones I have set. Currently my headers are being sent, but in addition there are also a number of other headers I didn't set.

This is how I'm adding custom headers:

```
$.ajax("http://fakedomain.foo", {headers: {header1: "value1", header2: "value2"}});
```

I might be fine even in case it's not possible to set the whole collection of headers, but only add extra ones. But even in this case, <strike>sometimes my headers are modified before being sent. For instance, if I add these headers</strike>:

```
    {
         "Connection": "close",
         "Accept-Encoding": "deflate, gzip",
         "Accept": "text/plain",
    }
```

<strike>Then this is what is actually being sent (I made a capture with Wireshark only to verify this)</strike>

```
    {
        "Connection": "close",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
        "Accept": "text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
        "Accept-Language": "es-ES,es;q=0.8",
        "Dnt": "1", 
        "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
        ...
    }
```

<strike>As you can see some evil gobling out there is tweaking my headers, and it has added the "sdch" encoding to the "Accept-Encoding" header, and also changed the "Accept" header so that it also accepts `*/*`. This is a real problem if the WS is picky and needs to take different actions based on the headers.</strike>

So to sum up:

1. Is there a way to send only my headers and no extra ones?

   <strike>2. If not, is there a way to add my custom headers as they are, without them being modified?</strike>

---

UPDATE:
My bad, I was not setting the headers properly. (The code I posted is correct, but there was a bug in my unit tests, so my headers were not actually added and the default ones were sent instead. After fixing this, I can see my headers are being sent with the correct text, and no modifications.
So forget about #2. The question #1 still applies.

Comment: 1) No. 2) No. The headers which get sent are dependant on the broswer, although they will all modify them in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification ([W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20060405/#dfn-setrequestheader), [WHATWG](http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method)) forbids overriding some headers, including `Accept-Encoding`.

Interestingly, the spec does not say anything special about `Accept`, which means the browser must use it as given. In this case it's jQuery at fault, where it [adds that last part](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/cb37994d76afb45efc3b606546349ed4e695c053/src/ajax.js#L594) just in case.
It was there since [6 years ago](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/5974495e6b1f40076ef257bc886dacd0c2e27bd7).

The specification also mandates the browser to send some other headers, such as `Authorization`, `Host`, `Connection`, `Keep-Alive`, and others.

Comment: You are right, actually the headers are not overriden. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Do you think my answer fully answers your question? If not, what do you think is missing?

Comment: Sorry I meant I'll edit my question. Forget about question #2, but thanks for posting the link to the specs. Now the only question remaining is #1.

Comment: It's described in the same spec that the browser must send some headers. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: I've read the W3C specs and it looks like the browser always sends some headers as you said. So I guess #1 is a NO. Interestingly, it also says "UAs MAY set the Accept-Charset and Accept-Encoding headers and MUST NOT allow them to be overridden". But in my tests I was able to set the Accept-Encoding.

Comment: Did you actually succeed in setting the `Accept-Encoding`? After all, the `gzip,deflate,sdch` is probably the default value of your browser.

Comment: Yup, I set it to "deflate, gzip" and that's exactly what was sent.

Comment: Hm. Well, it seems that the browser is validating the spec then, I suppose.